# Conflicting types for variadic parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to write a general invocation function.

It has the following syntax:

```
template<int Index, typename ReturnType, typename... Parameter>
ReturnType invokeGlobalFunction(Parameter... parameters)
{
    return invocator->invoke<ReturnType>(Index, parameters...);
}
```

Next, I try to derive two different function points from it, like this:

```
registerFunction(::someGlobalFunction, &invokeGlobalFunction<0, void>);
registerFunction(::someOtherFunction, &invokeGlobalFunction<1, int>);
```

Where `someGlobalFunction` has the prototype `void someGlobalFunction()` and `someOtherFunction` has the prototype `int someOtherFunction(int, const char *)`.

On the first call, it works like a charm, however the second call throws the error: `candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Parameter' (<int, const char *> vs. <>)`.

This implies, that the compiler (g++ 7.4.0 on an Ubuntu system btw.) does not overload the `invokeGlobalFunction` with the different parameter sets like I expected him to.

A note: When I explicitly set the parameter types on the call

```
registerFunction(::someOtherFunction, &invokeGlobalFunction<1, int, int, const char *>);
```

the compiler happily takes it, but I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

As a bonus, it would be great, if I could somehow create a unique function each time the index changes, because that would allow me to have functions with identical parameters but differing return types (which is illegal as far as I know).

Thank you.

Comment: Function template instance with another index is already unique. The complete name of instance includes all template parameters involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

Not with template functions, as far I know.

The problem is that a template parameter isn't a single object but a set of object where a function can accept only an object from the set.

When you write

```
&invokeGlobalFunction<1, int>
```

you choose a precise function with `Index = 1`, `ReturnType = int` and (this is the point) an empty  `Parameter...` list.

Suggestion: if you can, transform `invokeGlobalFunction()` in a template `struct` with a template method.

Something as

```
template <int Index, typename ReturnType>
struct invokeStruct
 {
   template <typename ... Parameters>
   ReturnType operator() (Parameters ... parameters)
    {
      // ... 
    }
  };
```

This way you have a set of struct with, in every struct, a set of `operator()` in it; passing a `invokeStruct<1, int>{}` as argument, you pass a single object but, inside it, you have available a set of method.

Comment: That looks clever.
There's just one problem...I need a pointer to a global function to store in a function pointer variable.

Thanks a lot anyway, also for the explanation.